# Image Animation behave diffrent after some navigation to tabs and get back on animation tab

Tags: android

**I have one method to set animation in imageview image**

*I want to change image after some interval and want set different animation for odd even image position*

```
// **** set Animation and image in imageview *****
private void setAnimation() {
     handler = new Handler();


    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {


        public void run() {

                imgView.setImageResource(setImg[i]);

                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.zoom_in_fade_out);
                    imgView.startAnimation(animation);
                    i++;
                } else {
                    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.zoom_out_fade_in);
                    imgView.startAnimation(animation);
                    i++;
                }


                if (i > setImg.length - 1) {
                    i = 0;
                }
```

handler.postDelayed(this, 8000);  //for interval...
            }

```
    };
   handler.postDelayed(runnable,10); //for initial delay..


}
```

*It work well but when I navigate to different tab for some time and get back to animation tab it behave different*

**Below is my Animation  xml **

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

>

```
<!-- ***** Set Zoom In Animation   *****-->
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="8000"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="500"
    android:toXScale="1.2"
    android:toYScale="1.2"/>

<!-- ***** Set Fade Out Animation   *****-->

<alpha
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="1"
    android:startOffset="500"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="0.8" />
```

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
```

>

```
<!-- ***** Set Fade In Animation   *****-->

<alpha
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.8"
    android:startOffset="500"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1" />

<!-- ***** Set Zoom Out Animation   *****-->
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="8000"
    android:fromXScale="1.2"
    android:fromYScale="1.2"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="500"
    android:toXScale="1"
    android:toYScale="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I solved my problem which I was faced. I changed Code like Below**

```
  @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i("TAG", "HOME RESUME");
    startTimer();


}
 @Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    stopTimerTask();
}

 @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i("TAG", "HOME PAUSE");stopTimerTask(); 

}
  public void startTimer() {
    //set a new Timer
    timer = new Timer();
    //initialize the TimerTask's job
    initializeTimerTask();
    //schedule the timer, after the first 0ms the TimerTask will run every 8000ms

    timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 8000); //
}

public void stopTimerTask() {

    //stop the timer, if it's not already null
    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();

        timer = null;
    }

}
public void initializeTimerTask() {

    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {

                    final Animation animation;
                    imgView.setImageResource(setImg[i]);

                    if (i % 2 == 0) {
                        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.anim.zoom_in_fade_out);
                        imgView.startAnimation(animation);

                    } else {
                        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity().getBaseContext(),R.anim.zoom_out_fade_in);
                        imgView.startAnimation(animation);

                    }
                    i++;
                    if (i >= setImg.length) {
                        i = 0;
                    }

                }

            });

        }

    };


}
```